# C++ IO binary file streams: default value when output isn't specified

Tags: c++, stl, fstream, ofstream

My question is about binary file I/O. Suppose the following code is run:

```
#include <iostream>
#inclide <fstream>

int main(){
    fstream out;
    out.open("binfile.bin",ios::binary|ios::out);
    if(!out.good()){
        cout<<"ain't good"<<endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    out.seekp(3);
    out<<char(74);
    out.seekp(7);
    out<<char(73);
    out.close();
}
```

binfile.bin contains `00 00 00 4A 00 00 00 49`, as expected. Can I somehow change that default value that is placed into the file if I don't specify what to output? I would like to replace `00` with something like `30`, so that binfile.bin would contain  `30 30 30 4A 30 30 30 49`, is that doable? Of course I can loop through the file at the end and replace all `00`s with `30`s, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Actually, it is undefined what those values will be - they are not required to be zero.

Comment: I recall there being a function to set the "fill character."  I don't know if that's what you're looking for, though.

Comment: @Maxpm: You are thinking of `setfill()`, which is used for formatted I/O when the field width specified using setw() exceeds the number of characters actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper for `seekp` and use that. Pseudocode:

```
my_seekp(fstream& f, int pos)
{
    seek to end
    endpos = position at end
    if (pos > endpos)
    {
        int n = endpos - pos;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            f.put(char(30));
    }
    else
        seek to pos
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of seeking and writing value as char using <<, what if you allocate a char buf[4] array, set your desired 'fill' value for all the elements, then just update the first/last element with the value you want and call out.write(buf, 4)?